# Android- two element on TableRow

Tags: java, android

I want to use two elements on row of table in my layout. EditText and ImageButton.
Here is my code:

```
<TableLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="*"
    android:stretchColumns="*" 
    android:background="#ffffff"
    tools:context=".CustomMainActivity" >   
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#b6006a">  
        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/ImageView1"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"            
            android:layout_weight="1"       
            android:padding="10dip" 
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:gravity="right"/> 

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="18dp" 
            android:text="Nava Messenger"           
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:background="#b6006a"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:gravity="left"/>  

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow0"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextViewSender"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:textColor="#000"/>  


    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">  
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:padding="18dip" 
            android:background="#fff"
            android:textColor="#000"/>  


    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">               
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText1"             
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:layout_width="0dp"                                 
            android:ellipsize="start"           
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Write a message..."
            android:textColor="#000000" />  
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/send_now"            
            android:gravity="right"/>           
    </TableRow>     

</TableLayout>
```

But result is different with what I thought before. Here is two output of this code on different phones:
[image]

[image]

All I want is restrict EditText and ImageButton to be on single line.

Answer (score 1):

Change your ImageButton as below.

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/send_now"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**you can use property padding top to imagebutton**
**i.e**

```
  <TableRow
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal">               
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText1"             
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:layout_width="0dp"                                 
            android:ellipsize="start"           
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Write a message..."
            android:textColor="#000000" />  
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton1"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/send_now"            
            android:gravity="right"/>           
    </TableRow>
```